# How to apply IF, else, else if condition in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, if-statement

I have a column in my pandas DataFrame with country names. I want to apply different filters on the column using if-else conditions and have to add a new column on that DataFrame with those conditions.

Current DataFrame:-

```html
Company Country
BV  Denmark
BV  Sweden
DC  Norway
BV  Germany
BV  France
DC  Croatia
BV  Italy
DC  Germany
BV  Austria
BV  Spain
```

I have tried this but in this, I have to define countries again and again.

**bookings_d2.loc[(bookings_d2.Country== 'Denmark') | (bookings_d2.Country== 'Norway'), 'Country'] =  bookings_d2.Country**

In R I am currently using if else condition like this, I want to implement this same thing in python.

**R Code Example 1 :
ifelse(bookings_d2$COUNTRY_NAME %in% c('Denmark','Germany','Norway','Sweden','France','Italy','Spain','Germany','Austria','Netherlands','Croatia','Belgium'),
                              as.character(bookings_d2$COUNTRY_NAME),'Others')**

 
 **R Code Example 2 :
ifelse(bookings_d2$country %in% c('Germany'),
                 ifelse(bookings_d2$BOOKING_BRAND %in% c('BV'),'Germany_BV','Germany_DC'),bookings_d2$country)**

Expected DataFrame:-

```html
Company Country
BV  Denmark
BV  Sweden
DC  Norway
BV  Germany_BV
BV  France
DC  Croatia
BV  Italy
DC  Germany_DC
BV  Others
BV  Others
```

Comment: I have pasted the snippet, Thanks

Comment: please use the HTML snippets (icon next to the picture) option to paste the input & output. That helps us to read the data as dataframe using `pandas.read_clipboard()`. we cannot use pictures for that purpose & most us will not want to waste time creating data frames by typing in data.

Comment: Hope now it will work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

For example1: Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series) with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or `loc`, but necessary invert mask by `~`:

```
#removed Austria, Spain
L = ['Denmark','Germany','Norway','Sweden','France','Italy',
     'Germany','Netherlands','Croatia','Belgium']

df['Country'] = np.where(df['Country'].isin(L), df['Country'], 'Others')
```

Alternative:

```
df.loc[~df['Country'].isin(L), 'Country'] ='Others'
```

For example2: Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) or nested `np.where`:

```
m1 = df['Country'] == 'Germany'
m2 = df['Company'] == 'BV'
df['Country'] = np.select([m1 & m2, m1 & ~m2],['Germany_BV','Germany_DC'], df['Country'])
```

Alternative:

```
df['Country'] = np.where(~m1, df['Country'],
                np.where(m2, 'Germany_BV','Germany_DC'))
print (df)
  Company     Country
0      BV     Denmark
1      BV      Sweden
2      DC      Norway
3      BV  Germany_BV
4      BV      France
5      DC     Croatia
6      BV       Italy
7      DC  Germany_DC
8      BV      Others
9      BV      Others
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, but I guess  it is something along the lines of:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'country':['Sweden','Spain','China','Japan'], 'continent':[None] * 4})

  country continent
0  Sweden      None
1   Spain      None
2   China      None
3   Japan      None


df.loc[(df.country=='Sweden') | ( df.country=='Spain'), 'continent'] = "Europe"
df.loc[(df.country=='China') | ( df.country=='Japan'), 'continent'] = "Asia"

  country continent
0  Sweden    Europe
1   Spain    Europe
2   China      Asia
3   Japan      Asia
```

You can also use python list comprehension like:

```
df.continent=["Europe" if (x=="Sweden" or x=="Denmark") else "Other" for x in df.country]
```

Comment: Saw you just updated the question, but the principle idea should be the same.

Comment: I want to achieve the same, but I want to know how we can do it with if and else condition. Your answer solves my question. But I wanna know how I can do it with if-else conditional statements.

Comment: you can think of the two df.loc statements as if, and elseif, then you can think of the initial [None] value as the else ( you are free to use any other value, doesn't have to be None).

Comment: @ArvindPant - Check dupe - `np.select`

Answer (score 1):

You can do to get it:

```
country_others=['Poland','Switzerland']


df.loc[df['Country']=='Germany','Country']=df.loc[df['Country']=='Germany'].apply(lambda x: x+df['Company'])['Country']
df.loc[(df['Company']=='DC') &(df['Country'].isin(country_others)),'Country']='Others'
```